# UIButton to navigate to WebView in another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I have an application with two ViewControllers. One has a WebView, and the other has a button. I wish that when pressed the button, carry a page in WebView in another ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

On button click,

```
-(void)ButtontnCliked:(UIButton*)sender 
{
  //create object of class to which you want to navigate.

  NewView *viewController = [[NewView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewView" bundle:nil]; //NewView is my new class
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];  // it will pushes your current view to newView.
  [viewController release];
}
```

**Note:** Assuming your rootViewController is navigation controller.